# Sum Array if a condition is met

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to sum (running sum) the values of an int Array and put the result in new array on corresponding position. If sum <0, result should be 0. 
I'm trying to find a better way to write below code? Maybe with streams java8?

```
    int[] originalArray = {3,7,-12,1,8,5};
    int[] resultArray= new int[originalArray.length];

    resultArray[0]=(originalArray[0]<0) ? 0:originalArray[0];

    for(int i=1;i<originalArray.length;i++){
        int sum=resultArray[i-1]+originalArray[i];
        resultArray[i]=(sum<0) ? 0 : sum;          
    //    System.out.println(resultArray[i]);        
    }
```

Comment: Since you calcuate the running sum with the previous running sum and you setting the sums to 0 if they are `< 0` you will get wrong results if there is any negative sum. Just use a summing variable on which you add the next items to.

Comment: the result is correct, I want to sum previous result with actual value.

Comment: Try Math.abs() if you only need the value then <?> or, are we missing smth ?

Comment: I will work with long arrays, I need to improve execution speed, if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need streams for this, a simple loop like you've already used is enough:

```
for (int i = 0, previous = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
    previous = resultArray[i] = Math.max(originalArray[i] + previous, 0);
}
```

You see that I introduced two things:

- `previous`: a helper variable, which tracks the previous result
- `Math.max()`: a useful method, it allows us to pick the result if it is positive or else `0` when it is negative (`0` is greater than any negative)

  The method looks something like this, which is exactly what you've done already:

  ```
  public static int max(int a, int b) {
      return (a >= b) ? a : b;
  }
  ```

---

If you don't like the multiple assignment line:

```
previous = resultArray[i] = Math.max(originalArray[i] + previous, 0);
```

Then you could also write it like this, if that's more understandable:

```
previous = Math.max(originalArray[i] + previous, 0);
resultArray[i] = previous;
```

Comment: Then I should stay with simple loop? I will work with long arrays, I need to improve execution speed, if possible.

Comment: @Daniel you only iterate once, so this is the fastest way possible

Comment: If you don’t need the original array anymore after the operation, you can use `Arrays.parallelPrefix(array, (a,b) -> Math.max(a+b, 0));` which might be faster for a sufficiently large array, but if you still need the original array, the required copying may be more expensive than any parallel processing benefit, as the sequential calculation shown in this answer is not much slower than the copying process. And if you use this method, mind that you have to manually check the first element for a negative value.

Comment: Ok, thinking about it again, the requirement to set negative sums to zero when makes the function non-associative, so it doesn’t work reliably with `parallelPrefix`.

Comment: @Daniel I did a simple benchmark with 1000 warmup runs, and 1000 real ones, got around `60` ms for an array of size `67108864` (`2^25`), so you may say that it runs quite fast. How big are your arrays if I may ask?

Comment: @Lino I did the same test and initial code with ternary operator was a bit faster than the one with Math. I'll use this one, thank you for your help.